Intercept and Modify SQLAlchemy Query with_hint
I have a Flask + SQLAlchemy application connected to SQL Server. I want to inject the with_hint method into every query emitted so that I can query system-temporal tables. I'd like to define an as-of-timestamp, t, for each request, then modify every query and all tables within those queries to include .with_hint(Model, 'FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF :t).
I'd like to do something like the global filter described here, but I can't figure out how to adapt it to:

Identify every model used in the query
Attach with_hint to every model
Inject the t parameter into the hint in the event handler

This is only relevant to SELECT queries. No need to handle INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.

You can indeed use events hooks to achieve this. I don't have a running MSSQL but I guess it should be the same since with_hint works for all dialects :
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, relationship, DeclarativeBase, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Table, Column, select, Integer, create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.sql.visitors import ClauseVisitor


# MODELS
class SubModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "submodel"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)


class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    sub_model_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(SubModel.id))
    sub_model = relationship(SubModel, uselist=False)

# DB config
engine = create_engine("mysql://...", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@event.listens_for(Session, "do_orm_execute")
def _do_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    if (
        orm_execute_state.is_select
        and not orm_execute_state.is_column_load
        and not orm_execute_state.is_relationship_load
    ):
        visitor = ClauseVisitor()
        for clause in visitor.iterate(orm_execute_state.statement):
            match clause:
                case Table():
                    orm_execute_state.statement = orm_execute_state.statement.with_hint(clause, "/*+ hint*/")
                case Column():
                    orm_execute_state.statement = orm_execute_state.statement.with_hint(clause.table, "/*+ hint*/")
                case _:
                    print("Did some tests but not 100% sure this covers everything")

# EXAMPLE

stmt = select(Model.id).join(Model.sub_model)
sess = Session()
sess.execute(stmt)
"""
> SELECT model.id 
FROM model /*+ hint*/ INNER JOIN submodel /*+ hint*/ ON submodel.id = model.sub_model_id
"""

